# T-SQL Duplicate, selecting 'master" record based on Modified Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database with two ID fields, one assigned as a GUID by the system, and a ExternalID, which is used to denote duplicates after data cleansing, the table also contains a ModifiedDate

I am trying to merge these records, with the most recently modified record absorbing the older accounts. I have tried the following query types.

```
SELECT 
a1.GUID
,a1.ModifiedDate
,a2.GUID
,a2,ModifiedDate
FROM Accounts a1
INNER JOIN Accounts a2 on a1.ExternalID = a2.ExternalID
```

This unfortunately causes the duplicate accounts to appear twice, once for the Master record, again for the subordinate record, which returns the Master record as a duplicate.

```
WITH Dup as (

SELECT 1 as track
,ExternalID DomEx
,ExternalID
,GUID DomGUID
,ModDate

from crm.Accounts
WHERE ExternalID is not null

UNION ALL

SELECT track +1 

,OI.DomEx
,OG.ExternalID
,OG.GUID
,Og.ModDate

from crm.Accounts OG
INNER JOIN Dup OI on OI.ExternalID = OG.ExternalID

)
,
cte_dp as(
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ExternalID Order by track, ModDate desc) rn
FROM Dup
)

SELECT * FROM cte_dp
```

This unfortunately reaches the recursion limit of 100, and runs indefinitely if the limit is escaped.

Is it possible to correct the logic here in order to present the results required, or is there a more elegant solution.

```
+--------------+---------------------+--------------------+--+
|  MasterGUID  |  SharedExternalID   |  SubordinateGUID   |  |
+--------------+---------------------+--------------------+--+
| (MasterGUID) | (SharedExternalID)  | (SubordinateGUID)  |  |
| (MasterGUID) | (Shared ExternalID) | (SubordinateGUID)  |  |
+--------------+---------------------+--------------------+--+
```

Is the result I would ideally like to achieve, with MasterGUID being the GUID with the most recent modified date from between the two duplicates.

Comment: Can you post sample and expected data?

Comment: Edited above, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE Accounts a1
USING Accounts a2
ON a1.ExternalID = a2.ExternalID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET a1.ModifiedDate = a2.ModifiedDate,
  a1.guid = a2.guid;

SELECT * FROM Accounts a1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a1.ExternalID = a2.ExternalID
```

is symmetric, so if you switch the order, the relationship will have the same logical result. So, if you find such a pair (for instance, self), then it will appear twice in the result. We need to break the symmetry with an additional condition:

```
a1.ExternalID = a2.ExternalID and a1.GUID < a2.GUID
```

This will prevent joining with self. If that is needed, you can use `union`, but for now I will assume that is not needed. If there is another match of `ExternalID`, the match will yield true if the left side has a strictly smaller `GUID` than the right side, therefore the inverse will not be true and the duplicates will go away.

Answer (score 0):

If you post sample data this will be easier but is this what you mean?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ExternalID ORDER BY ModifiedDate DESC) rnk
    from accounts 
) i
WHERE i.rnk = 1
```